# how to start with php code sniffer

Tags: php, ubuntu, phpcodesniffer

I have all written code and i want to this code standarise by php code sniffer. I would like to know what is the best way to start with it. I had installed it but when i run the command

```
 phpcs /path/to/code/myfile.php
```

In the command line I got the last one hundered  line error from 310 to 410. But if I want to see the starting errors of any line error how can I see that. Mostly errors are :

```
 322 | ERROR   | Spaces must be used to indent lines; tabs are not allowed
 322 | ERROR   | Line indented incorrectly; expected at least 8 spaces, found 2
```

How can I solve these things easily and in future it don't repeat, what it saying that I should not use tab, and use space, by using space it will take time.

And how can I start with basic standard, because don't want to utilize more time in this right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the output to summary only with command line option...

```
--config-set report_format summary
```

[All options](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.php.php-codesniffer.config-options.php).